# My Lenovo Ideapad u165 wireless doesn't work 

Tags: wireless, broadcom, lenovo

It really makes me ANGRY !  my wireless hardware is broadcom 4313 . ubuntu install it automatically but I can't use it . It says your hardware switch is off although it is on . after I use " `rfkill unblock all` " for several times it says your device isn't ready !! 
this is my rfkill list :

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

after I unblock all :

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

plz help me ! I use windows only for wireless !!!!

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 stopped working again. Any help will be highly appreciated.

  krasi@krasi-ideapad:~$ rfkill list
  0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
  1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no 
  2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I upgrade too but there is no problem !! maybe you should turn it on in windows and then restart and login to ubuntu !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It realy works!
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
add
    blacklist acer_wmi

to do this write
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

then enter the password

go to a clean line and pres the insert key, this will enable input mode in vi

write

blacklist acer_wmi

then pres esc key several times.

then write  :wq!  then pres enter

(for sayfty back up the file first, once the acer_wmi is blacklisted reboot )

reboot

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment but can't sorry!

which version of Ubuntu are you using? I encountered the same problem when I upgraded to Natty on my Lenovo Ideapad, also Broadcom 4313. 
You could try the solutions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1700897

Ultimately I downgraded because nothing worked for me & everything is fine now. I'll wait for the next LTS. Hopefully you'll find a solution! I shifted my home to a separate partition so that I can do fresh installs without erasing my documents.

Comment: I use 11.04 and I used this method and I don't have any problem any more .

Answer (score 1):

For my Lenovo U160 I blacklisted the acer_wmi module and afterwards the wireless worked perfectly. Maybe that solves it for you as well.

in

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

add

> blacklist acer_wmi