# WiFi is not enabled  in Network Manager with a BCM4313

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom, lenovo

Help please. Put it on the computer ubuntu 11.10 64bit. Used the response in the topic [WiFi does not work, Broadcom STA Wireless driver does not work on a BCM4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50970/wifi-does-not-work-broadcom-sta-wireless-driver-does-not-work-on-a-bcm4313) but this does not help. Computer Lenovo z570, wifi card Broadcom Corporation BCM4313

When choosing Network Manager > Enable Wireless nothing happens. WiFi not enabling.

Comment: Similar question here - does the answer work for you?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/66674/after-upgrading-to-11-10-my-lenovo-u165-wireless-bcm4313-stopped-working

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem today on ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, but my platform is an acer 4755g.

1st of all, let's be absolutely sure that your z570 is using a broadcom
http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/uk/en/DriversDownloads/drivers_list.aspx?CategoryID=307140

as you can see, z570 supports 
1. intel (several diff types)
2. broadcom
3. Atheros

You do this by
1. opening a terminal
2. running the command

alvinh@ibmsda6:~$ lspci | egrep -i "Atheros|broadcom|intel"

This is my other pc which also run ubuntu 11.10, but the i386 version
02:02.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)

In your question, you were very specific that you have a BCM4313, so i'm gonna take yr word for it. Let's assume that you've done a lspci & it returns "wireless" & "broadcom" on the same line since this is the only hardware that supports 64bit.

1. Now install this package
   http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/b43-fwcutter

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter

1. when that's done, goto System Settings (should be on the launcher on the left)
   Hardware/Additional Drivers -> Broadcom <- Enable this driver
2. The rest is the same as previous releases of ubuntu; on the top right-hand, click on the LAN & configure your wireless lan info.

Good luck Alex; this is as best as i can do for you bec it's exactly what i did!

Answer (score 2):

This is what helped me:

The Broadcom STA driver under *System Settings* should be installed. Check if *acer-wireless* is blocked via

> rfkill list all

If it is blocked then edit your *blacklist.conf* and add following:

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Then restart and all should work fine. It's strange, but it works without problems.

> **Related**
>   [Cannot enable wireless on an Intel WifiLink 1000 on an Lenovo Ideapad z570](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97910/cant-enable-wireless-on-an-intel-wifilink-1000-on-an-lenovo-ideapad-z570)

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't have Internet running on the Ubuntu machine/boot.
Download the b43 driver from the above link and then use the following command to install it.

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_014-9_i386.deb
```

Replace the filename with the one's you have downloaded move to the folder you have downloaded the file.

Now reboot, hopefully the WiFi is working now.