# Broadcom BCM4313 on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Broadcom BCM 43XX Wireless card working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-get-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-card-working)

Okay so I've this afternoon updated the family laptop to 11.10. But our broadcom BCM4313 wireless card has stopped working. I tried googling and found someone saying you have to install a deb named 'b43-fwcutter_014-9_i386' and select the new driver but the driver did  not appear in my list.

The laptop is a compaq Cq56

```
***
```

lshw output http://pastebin.com/KNTj6fLt

```
rfkill 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

it's worth noting that I've pressed the wireless key that usually turns the colour of a little light on the key from orange to white. But it just stays orange now. Also after plugging in an ether cable and selecting it from network manager I still can't access the Internet on the laptop. Though that problem existed even on 11.04 when the wireless worked.

---

Okay I installed a driver that was older then the current one that was in use. After rebooting several times the wifi is now back on. When I installed it and rebooted once it didn't work. Wonder why it did after I did rebooted several times?

For a moment I thought to install Windows. Don't judge me. I was weak. I don't know what came over me.

Comment: you've got a hard-block - that means a physical switch is blocking, not software.  This can be a Fn key, a slide switch or button.  Some switches can be very discrete (under a battery for example).  What is your laptop and its model?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm43xx-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look to my answer on the following question

[How do I get the Broadcom BCM4313 wireless working on an Asus 1015PX?](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/94021/how-do-i-get-the-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-working-on-an-asus-1015px)

Comment: Tried several of those fixes. But no avail.

Answer (score 0):

PTbuntu answer does not do it for me, this one does http://drndivoje.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/how-to-enable-broadcom-wireless-bcm4311-card-on-linux-mint-11/