# BCM4313 wireless not working on Dell Inspiron 4010

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed today and trying to connect to wireless but its not working. It has been working correctly on my Windows 7. i am pretty new to Ubuntu. I tried suggestions listed in this forum but nothing seems to be working for wireless.

It shows wireless card listed when I do- sudo lshw -C network:
It displays wireless interface as BCM4313.

my laptop- Dell Inspiron 4010
Ubuntu- 11.10

Any suggestions?

It works when I connect LAN cable to same modem.

Comment: Please look at this question to see if this resolves your issue:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/94021/how-do-i-get-the-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-working-on-an-asus-1015px

Answer (score 1):

Connect your PC to the internet via LAN. Open terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Reboot and Wifi should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing proprietary drivers? To do this, you need to:

1. Connect to the internet with a LAN connection
2. Check if any proprietary drivers are available

   - via System Settings, or:
   - by running `jockey-gtk` in a terminal
3. Restart to enable the new drivers

---

Other tips:

- Make the network public (visible SSID) and check if it's visible in Ubuntu
- Try connecting to any other WLAN, to check if there might be some problem with the network configuration