# cannot find "Enable Wireless" option in Ubuntu 12.04 network drop down

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

Historically, there is an "Enable Wireless" option that I can have ticked or unticked that is just beneath the "Enable Networking" option when I right click on the network bar.

Suddenly this disappeared one day, and I can't connect to wireless, nor does the option even exist to enable wireless.

The output for rfkill list all is below:

```
rfkill list all
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

And that is all. There is no wireless that is being displayed.

The output for sudo lshw -C network is:

```
    *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 28:d2:44:4d:b6:89
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.0.0-k duplex=full firmware=0.6-3 ip=10.0.28.48 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:57 memory:f0600000-f061ffff memory:f063e000-f063efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0400000-f0401fff
```

Does anyone know how I can enable wireless? I have also tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and have checked to make sure drivers are up to date as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same discussion :
I recommend to you to follow it, to resolv your problem !

["Enable Wireless" option is disabled in network settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152157/enable-wireless-option-is-disabled-in-network-settings)

Comment: Yea i already went through all of those but none of it worked. It appears to be a different case as their wireless still appears when they do rfkill list all, whereas mine doesn't even show up there at all....

Comment: You do not have a driver loaded for your device. either it is not loaded and needs loaded manually or you need to install the driver which normally for intel devices is not the case.