# How to install a wireless adapter D-Link DWA-131?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, adapter, d-link

Recently I built new PC with Ubuntu OS 14.04 (64bit). I noticed the D-Link Wireless N Nano USB Adapter doesn't get detected and installed automatically.

Following are the adapter specifications:

- Model No: DWA-131
- Hardware Version : E1
- Firmware Version : 5.00

How to install this wireless adapter?

Comment: Sounds as if, after a diligent search on your part, your hardware is not linux compatible. Your options are to contact the vendor and ask for a linux driver, write a kernel module for yourself, or purchase Linux compatible hardware. Of the 3, linux compatible hardware is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 5):

I added a driver for this adapter to PPA. It can be installed by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 15.10.

Comment: Did it build without errors? Did you install some other drivers? Are you sure you have a 8192eu device? You'd better ask a new question.

Comment: [This solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/738997/413683) works for me so I'll just stick to it.

Comment: It did not work for you, because you installed another driver and blacklisted `rtl8192eu`. It is OK to use another way, but not both.

Comment: At first I tried the one from your repo but it didn't work. The interface showed up in the Wifi menu in the system tray after installation. It disappeared after rebooting however.

Comment: It is weird. Many people use it.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me , i did this and also did what is told in answer of this question
 http://askubuntu.com/questions/152157/enable-wireless-option-is-disabled-in-network-settings

 , rebooting the system made it work i am running ubuntu 16.04 !!

Answer (score 2):

Here's exactly what and where you have to edit:

- Download [the source of the DWA-131 (version E1) Linux driver](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DWA-131/REV_E/Drivers/).
- Extract your source and go to `/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/os_dep/linux/`.
- Edit  the `os_intfs.c` file.
- Search for the following line: `DBG_871X_LEVEL(_drv_info` and 
  change

  ```
  #endif
          return NOTIFY_DONE;

      DBG_871X_LEVEL(_drv_info_, FUNC_NDEV_FMT" state:%lu\n", FUNC_NDEV_ARG(dev), state);

      switch (state) {
      case NETDEV_CHANGENAME:
          rtw_adapter_proc_replace(dev);
          break;
      }

      return NOTIFY_DONE;
  }
  ```

  into

  ```
  #endif
          return NOTIFY_DONE;

      //ed, 20150426 //DBG_871X_LEVEL(_drv_info_, FUNC_NDEV_FMT" state:%lu\n", FUNC_NDEV_ARG(dev), state);

      switch (state) {
      case NETDEV_CHANGENAME:
          //ed,20150426 //rtw_adapter_proc_replace(dev);
          break;
      }

      return NOTIFY_DONE;
  }
  ```

  You have to actually insert this: `//ed, 20150426 //`
- Then write the file and do:

  1. `make`
  2. `make install`
- I also did the following:

  ```
  wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.0.0/compat-wireless-3.0-2.tar.bz2
  tar jxvf compat-wireless-3.0-2.tar.bz2
  make
  make install
  ```

  (Please note that the `build-essential` package is already installed on the machine. You'll have to `apt-get install` it if you want to be able to `make` and `make install` anything on the machine.)

Hope this helps make the process clearer. Thanks to the first author for the files to modify.

Fabrice Clerc

Comment: Why do you need to install this guy? *compat-wireless-3.0-2.tar.bz2*

Comment: If I try `make` I get the error `Makefile:1329: recipe for target 'modules' failed`... ideas how to solve this? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Same issue here  recipe for target 'modules' failed , ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 16.10 (couldn't compile).

Comment: can you explain why you have to edit that file?

Answer (score 0):

This way is working on my desktop (x86_64, ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-49-generic). For your reference.

1. Download [the source of the DWA-131 (ver:E1) linux driver.](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DWA-131/REV_E/Drivers/)
2. Extract the zip file (DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1.zip)
3. Modify two lines (//ed, 20150426 //...) in the `rtw_ndev_notifier_call()` function, file name `os_intfs.c`.

   ```
   return NOTIFY_DONE;
   //ed, 20150426 //DBG_871X_LEVEL(_drv_info_, FUNC_NDEV_FMT" state:%lu\n", FUNC_NDEV_ARG(dev), state);

   switch (state) {    case NETDEV_CHANGENAME:         //ed, 20150426 //rtw_adapter_proc_replace(dev);         break;  }
   ```
4. compile the codes. (refer to `readme.txt` in the downloaded package)

   ```
   make
   ```
5. install the driver

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: Can you please **edit your answer** and explain a bit more which lines to change to what? I find your explanation very confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue after upgrading from 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.
The goal is to download the last driver for rtl8192eu adapted to the newest kernels (up to 5.18)

**Install Drivers in new Kernel versions**

1. Go to this Github repo and download the adpated Driver
   https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

- **TIP:** If you don't have internet access in the PC, use your phone, set the Desktop view (i.e. Chrome) and download the repo selecting "CODE" --> "Download ZIP" and then copy the .zip file into the PC.

2. Build the Driver using the automated script **./install_wifi.sh**

- **IMPORTANT:** It is necessary to have installed those packages *"linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms"*.

3. After finishing the script (and without restarting) the WiFi icon will be shown in the Task Bar (up right corner).

**Path to the official linux drivers**
In this path are located the official released drivers --> But only supports 18.04

- http://files.dlink.com.au/products/DWA-131/REV_E/Drivers/