# Installing wireless adapter D-Link DWA-131 Version : E1 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, internet, network-manager

I followed the steps mention in [How to install a wireless adapter D-Link DWA-131?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591016/how-to-install-wireless-adapter-d-link-dwa-131) for installation
But I am getting the below error after entering the make command:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/build M=/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320  modules

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic'

  CC [M]  /media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_cmd.o

  CC [M]  /media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_security.o

  CC [M]  /media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.o

/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c: In function ‘dump_drv_version’:

/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c:66:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "build time: %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                                ^
/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "build time: %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
 ^

/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.o' failed

make[2]: *** [/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/core/rtw_debug.o] Error 1

Makefile:1395: recipe for target '_module_/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320' failed

make[1]: *** [_module_/media/sachin/SACHIN/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic'

Makefile:1323: recipe for target 'modules' failed

make: *** [modules] Error 2
```