# Install DWA-131 WiFi dongle driver under Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, adapter, d-link

[How to install a wireless adapter D-Link DWA-131?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591016/how-to-install-wireless-adapter-d-link-dwa-131)

The solution which worked under Ubuntu 14.04.1 is not working under Ubuntu 14.04.4.

Even the make process itself gives errors.

Is there any permanent solution for this without any worries for higher Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please open a terminal and, with a temporary working internet connection, do:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

You will have installed the driver for your current kernel version only. After Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, you must recompile:

```
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Works on BunsenLabs as well.

Comment: Works like a charm on Linux Mint 17

Comment: Awesssommmmme. Works on Ubuntu 16.10 yakkety

Comment: Does not work for 17.04 :(

Comment: @DmitryVinokurov Ubuntu 17.04 is long since end-of-life. I suggest that you install 18.04 LTS and try again.

Comment: @chili555, tried already - does not work too.

Comment: @DmitryVinokurov Please start a new question and I will be happy to help.

Comment: @chili555, thanks for help suggestion - here it is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069137/d-link-dwa-131-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks. Works on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Answer (score 2):

I added this driver to my ppa. It builds for kernels 4.2.

If you install it from the PPA, then you will not have to re-install it after kernel updates.

The driver can be installed by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

If you installed a driver from github, you need to uninstall it first.

Comment: As I am new to Ubuntu, if you can let me know about how to create my own PPA and how to add this driver to my ppa, I will be thankful to you.

Comment: @nb5691 You can install this driver from my PPA. If you want to create your own PPA, you can find manuals in the net. But it is not for newbies.