# How to install driver for D-Link DWA-181 AC1300 Wifi USB adaptor?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, d-link

I purchased a wireless USB adaptor because my operating system, Kubuntu 18.04, is no longer detecting my wifi card.

When I purchased it, I thought it would be the type of Wifi USB adaptor that you simply need to plug and it works right away, but when I unpacked it I unfortunately realized that it would be a little more complex to get it to work.

I was able to find and download the zip file of the driver for Linux (DWA-181_REVA_DRIVERS_v5.8.7.1_LINUX.zip) on the website of D-Link, but they don't provide any guide for how to install it.

How do I install the driver?

Answer (score 4):

I dont have this specific wifi module to test it out myself, but just building driver from source should work.

First install dependencies depending on your package manager this can be done on Debian/Ubuntu using apt:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Next unzip the downloaded folder, and unzip the file in there, and there should be a folder called `driver` with a driver tarball, with the name `rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.7.1_*.tar.gz`, decompress in whatever fashion you see fit, I simply right clicked in dolphin and extracted, open the newly decompressed folder and open a terminal to this location.

Now run:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe DWA_181
```

And your local Network Manager should pick up the wireless card from there.

Comment: Thank you both! I will try every option if necessary.  Sayed, I tried the steps you suggested but the last command "sudo modprobe DWA_181" didn't work.  I also tried to run the same command with a hyphen (DWA-181) instead of an underscore, but it seems like it made no difference.  Both times I got:  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'DWA_181': Operation not permitted       Do you have any idea what else I could try?  I could mention that I see 5 files with the name DWA-181:  They have the extensions ko, mod, mod.c, mod.o, o.

Comment: @EricMather have you got secure boot enabled? that would be a secure boot related issue, as it locks down the insertion of unsigned drivers into the kernel, you'll have to sign the driver before you can run mod probe or turn off secure boot

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver thank you!!!

Comment: Glorious.  I just found and used this answer _again_.  Had to dig out my S/O password for this new computer to upvote, and found I already had last time.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The official driver from D-Link mentioned in the question is [here](https://support.dlink.com/resource/products/DWA-181/REVA/DRIVERS/LINUX/).

However, the latest driver provided by ***DWA-181_REVA_DRIVERS_v5.8.7.1_LINUX*** won’t work with newer Linux kernel, you’ll encounter compiler error: `No such file or directory net/ipx.h`.  This is due to a [change in the Linux kernel starting from **5.15**](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/include/net?id=6c9b40844751ea30c72f7a2f92f4d704bc6b2927).

I would recommend two up-to-date repositories for anyone who’d like to compile the driver themselves.

- https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702
- https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver

I’ve tested the first one, it works perfectly with D-Link DWA-181 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-57-generic x86_64).

Comment: the first one worked for me!! thaaankssss

Answer (score 0):

could you please check if its detected in lsusb.
These might be helpful but
https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_26334.20180126_COEX20171012-5044
There seems to be a similar issue with this adapter for 14.04 answered [Install DWA-131 WiFi dongle driver under Ubuntu 14.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738911/install-dwa-131-wifi-dongle-driver-under-ubuntu-14-04-4?rq=1) so you can try with that solution first and then check the others.

This is the third thing i found that might work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

And if nothing works search for errors regarding the device in /var/log/syslog (less /var/log/syslog | grep error).