# "wireless connection" option missing in network settings

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, installed the rtl8723be driver and WiFi worked fine for few months but then it used to stop responding after a while (may be for 5 mins or so).

I followed the 1st solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem) link to fix the problem.
When I rebooted my system, the "wireless connection" option disappeared in the network settings. I tried the first solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152157/enable-wireless-option-is-disabled-in-network-settings) link, but it didn't help neither.

This might be useful:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Nov 2015 12:57 IST +0530

Booted last: 11 Nov 2015 00:50 IST +0530

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.1.0-rc7+ #5 SMP Wed Sep 2 09:06:11 IST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### dkms status #######################
rtl8723au_bt, 0.7.1~trusty, 4.1.0-rc7+, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.5~trusty, 4.1.0-rc7+, x86_64: installed

##### rfkill ############################

1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211              741376  0 
snd_soc_rt5640         94208  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          196608  1 snd_soc_rt5640
cfg80211              552960  1 mac80211
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
ideapad_laptop         20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14487680 (14.4 MB)  TX bytes:1729997 (1.7 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       907     1  0 00:50 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: <MAC address> ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:

- Device: eth0  [Ethernet connection 1] ----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.4
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BCFC-c3M]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BCFC-c3M | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BCFC-c3M | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/No-Network]] (600 root)
[connection] id=No-Network | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=No-Network | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/praneetha]] (600 root)
[connection] id=praneetha | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=praneetha | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vindhya@iiith]] (600 root)
[connection] id=vindhya@iiith | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=vindhya@iiith | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Computer Planet]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Computer Planet | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Computer Planet | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/nilgiri@iiith]] (600 root)
[connection] id=nilgiri@iiith | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=nilgiri@iiith | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Pal.]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Pal. | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Pal. | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vindhya@iiith 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=vindhya@iiith 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=vindhya@iiith | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Nilgiri3-5]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Nilgiri3-5 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Nilgiri3-5 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/shrutigupta 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=shrutigupta 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=shrutigupta | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Nuts-Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Nuts-Hotspot | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Nuts-Hotspot | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/pathak]] (600 root)
[connection] id=pathak | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=pathak | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VindhyaOAP1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VindhyaOAP1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=VindhyaOAP1 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/nilgiri@iiith 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=nilgiri@iiith 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=nilgiri@iiith | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/susanth]] (600 root)
[connection] id=susanth | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=susanth | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/belkin.eb8]] (600 root)
[connection] id=belkin.eb8 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=belkin.eb8 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Himalaya@iiith]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Himalaya@iiith | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Himalaya@iiith | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BPS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BPS | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BPS | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/shrutigupta]] (600 root)
[connection] id=shrutigupta | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=shrutigupta | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Atlantis]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Atlantis | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Atlantis | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/belkin.116]] (600 root)
[connection] id=belkin.116 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=belkin.116 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/manasawifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=manasawifi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=manasawifi | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MSIT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MSIT | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MSIT | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BCFC-c3M 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BCFC-c3M 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BCFC-c3M | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sritej Kamishetty’s MacBook Pr]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sritej Kamishetty’s MacBook Pr | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=83;114;105;116;101;106;32;75;97;109;105;115;104;101;116;116;121;226;128;153;115;32;77;97;99;66;111;111;107;32;80;114; | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.1.0-rc7+/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     5F217E3E605BFE2A9C4566D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.1.0-rc7+ SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        31:7F:06:38:62:DB:A9:43:7C:B4:DB:30:73:A7:36:B2:39:64:6D:25
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.1.0-rc7+/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     589E4A864ED1FA35C9018BE
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.1.0-rc7+ SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        31:7F:06:38:62:DB:A9:43:7C:B4:DB:30:73:A7:36:B2:39:64:6D:25
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   72.239947] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
[   72.239957] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  421.969500] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  424.735891] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[  424.735896] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[  427.399529] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[  427.399576] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  429.000414] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
[  429.000422] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  433.205928] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[  434.849920] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up

########## wireless info END ############
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: output of dkms status :  rtl8723au_bt, 0.7.1~trusty, 4.1.0-rc7+, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtlwifi-new, 0.5~trusty, 4.1.0-rc7+, x86_64: installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an unsupported kernel 4.1.0-rc7+.

I suggest to remove the drivers first by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove rtlwifi-new-dkms rtl8723au-bt-dkms
```

Then install a supported kernel 4.2 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Probably Wi-Fi will work OK after reboot. If not, then try to install `rtlwifi-new-dkms`.