# Wifi connections not showing in menu (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, drivers

Not getting the option to select or even able the wireless connections in networking tab. Have also tried to restart the system couple of times and still not working.

Following are the output on executing the command:

1. Executing `lspci -vnn | grep Network`:

   > 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
2. Executing `iwconfig`:
   `eth0      no wireless extensions.
   lo        no wireless extensions.`
3. Executing `lspci`:
   `00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
   00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 0b)
   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
   00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
   00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
   00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
   01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
   02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
   03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 6900 (rev ff)`
4. Executing `rfkill list all`:
   `0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: yes
   1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: yes`

Just a note: It was working fine till yesterday night, suddenly stopped working now.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS. Default kernel i believe is 3.x. I had Intel 3165 wifi card in my laptop and I was also not getting any wifi symbols to even connect. As per Intel it(3165) was supported only in kernel 4.1+. So i tried some of the quick fixes as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723446/wifi-issue-should-i-upgrade-the-kernel). That fixed the issue temporarily - I will get wifi for few hours and then it will get disconnected. But finally i upgraded my kernel to 4.2.5 as mentioned in that link. That fixed all my wifi related issues. Try the solution that i am proposing and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I am afraid of upgrading the kernel as whenever tried doing so on my OS (12.04 LTS) it lend me in lot of trouble (re-installing the OS). Sorry, therefore I will prefer to wait for alternate solution. Hope you wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue resolved after enabling the wifi through `fn` + `PrtScr` key. Following command hinted the issue:

Executing `rfkill list all`:

`0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes`

Reference:
[“Enable Wireless” option is disabled in network settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152157/enable-wireless-option-is-disabled-in-network-settings)