# Wireless disabled on 12.10 Macbook pro 7.1

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I have a Mac book pro 7,1 and triple booted it by (OSX10.6,Windows7,Ubuntu12.10)
every 3 OS boots normally and everything is ok. Just Ubuntu does not recognize my Wireless

According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Quantal#Wireless_.28AirPort.29) I should have something under Additional Drivers, but the box is empty.

I used the lspci command or lsusb command on terminal no wireless (broadcom) driver shows up.

Answer (score 1):

execute this in terminal

/etc/init.d/networking restart

it should fix your problem

Comment: I executed the command on terminal and it suggested to execute this insteed: service networking restart. but neither one worked :(

Comment: i think this link is what you need http://askubuntu.com/questions/94021/how-do-i-get-the-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-working-on-an-asus-1015px/97368#97368

Comment: didnt work either one. but thanks anyway. any help would be appreciated