# Can't connect to the internet after Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: internet

Not sure really where to begin. This would be my first attempt at using a non windows or Mac OS. Had read some decent things about Ubuntu but never got around to playing around with it until recently when I thought I'd give it a try on my olderish PC.

Everything seemed fine when I was running off the usb disk image. But now that I've gone for the full install, I can't seem to connect to my wireless network even though my network seems to be connected according to the network connections manager.

I've tried setting IPv6 settings to ignore. I've set IPv4 settings to auto dhcp only and set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 . I've logged into my router and set my security to WPA2 AES. But none of these things seems to have made a difference.

When I open up firefox I get an unable to connect error message regardless of the changes.

If I need to completely reinstall the OS I'm able to do that so I can start again from scratch, but I have tried that once already and haven't had any luck.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that's pretty basic (hopefully) I just don't know where to start.

Anyway, thanks for any help/advice/criticism.
P

EDIT: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23639646/

Comment: Run the [`wireless-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/blob/master/wireless-info) and paste it over on https://paste.ubuntu.com. Please then [edit] your question to include a link to this paste.

Comment: OMG you broke the internet !

Comment: So I'm currently on my phone and am not having much luck figuring out how to be able to execute that script on my pc. Or maybe I'm not seeing the easy answer. Like I said extreme novice here. Apoligies for my ignorance

Comment: @bodhi it sure feels that way. Hope I haven't broken your end too

Comment: run that script from a live usb , the same one you used to install, where your wireless was working or use a wired network until you get it sorted.

Comment: well that took longer than I thought it would. Thanks for the walkthrough @bodhi. let me know what I need to do next. Thanks and apologies again

Comment: You have a BCM4313 chip , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/94021/how-do-i-get-the-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-working-on-an-asus-1015px