# Cannot enable wireless on an Intel WifiLink 1000 on an Lenovo Ideapad z570

Tags: 11.10, lenovo, intel-wireless, ideapad

I am using the ubuntu 11.10 on lenovo ideapad z570. My wireless internet is not working.

I have ensure that wireless switch is on. Windows 7, wireless works great.However ubuntu 11.10 is not allowing me to enable wireless connection.

I have run the

following command and here is the status.

> sudo lshw -class network

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:e5:0b:1c:a4:a4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:42 memory:d0500000-d0501fff


  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: f0:de:f1:64:b6:62
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

Here is rfkill list all output:

rfkill list all

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Note : Windows 7, wireless card property shows that Intel WifiLink 1000 BGN.
Could someone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rfkill-list results indicate a soft-block issue.

Try blacklisting the acer-wmi kernel module:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add `blacklist acer_wmi` as a new line at the bottom of this file.

then reboot.

After reboot rerun `rfkill list all` - hopefully your soft-block value is changed from "Yes" to "No" - your wireless should now be re-enabled.

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom.  I did and it works :) You are awesome. I also read solution you provided to one another question. I could have used that solution before but confused about the Acer wifeless. I thought mine is intel :) Anyway thanks a lot for your help