# How to make pcmanfm to display the column "Permissions" in detailed view - Lubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, openbox, lxde

I decided to try Lubuntu  after [my problem with wireless on Lenovo u165](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66674/after-upgrading-to-11-10-my-lenovo-u165-wireless-bcm4313-stopped-working/66898#66898).

I did not know my netbook is so fast :)! Great performance.

However I miss some things from Nautilus.
I searched but did not find anywhere help how to add "Permissions" column in Detailed List View.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately pcmanfm [does not support this feature](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:D1bYAt4i3iYJ:forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=4297%20pcmanfm%20add%20permissions%20column&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu).  Strangely, you had this ability in v0.5.x of pcmanfm - but this feature has been *removed* in subsequent versions...

XFCE and LXDE share many components - they can be interchangeable.

For example - you could use *thunar* instead of *pcmanfm* as your file-manager

[image]

As you can see - you can configure thunar with additional columns such as permissions.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it right away. How eventually to set thunar as the default file manager?

Comment: ... good question ... why dont you post just that :)

Comment: Done. http://askubuntu.com/questions/73017/thunar-as-default-file-manager-in-lubuntu-11-10-how