# Thunar as default file manager in Lubuntu 11.10 - how?

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu, thunar

PCmanFM misses the permission column in its detail view and the ability to set viewable columns. Because of this I switched to Thunar.
Now I want to set it as my default file manger  in LXDE.
How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The simple way...

The quickest way is to create a *pcmanfm* shell script in `/usr/local/bin`.  This shell script will instead execute *thunar*

Thus:

```
nano ~/pcmanfm
```

copy and paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
thunar $* &
```

Save

```
chmod 755 ~/pcmanfm
sudo mv ~/pcmanfm /usr/local/bin
```

The disadvantage though of this method is that you will lose any desktop shortcuts because on login, pcmanfm is no longer being run on login.

### LXDE/XFCE Hybrid

A more interesting method would be to have the LXDE shell but with the XFCE desktop rather than the pcmanfm desktop

[image]

The reason for running with the xfdesktop is that it integrates with thunar whereas the pcmanfm desktop cannot be configured to launch folders stored on the desktop with thunar - only pcmanfm.

The recipe is as follows:

- Change the default file-manager shortcut: edit the file `/usr/share/applications/pcmanfm.desktop` and change the line `Exec=pcmanfm %U` to `Exec=thunar %U`
- Change shortcut keys: using `leafpad` change all references of `pcmanfm` to `thunar` in the file `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`
- Stop pcmanfm desktop being run on login: edit the file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` and change the line `@pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu` to `!@pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu`
- Create a startup-on-login folder: create a folder called `~/.config/autostart`
- Start `xfdesktop` on login: create a file called `xfdesktop.desktop` in this autostart folder with...

the contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=xfdesktop
Icon=help-contents
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;
Name=xfdesktop
```

- Install xfdesktop: `sudo apt-get install xfdesktop4`
- reboot.

## a third way...

If you don't want to run the xfdesktop - then follow the recipe above, but dont disable pcmanfm in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` and you also dont need to autostart `xfdesktop`.

Obviously you are still left with the *folder on desktop launching pcmanfm* issue - but if you can live with this, this is a worthy compromise.

Comment: shouldn' there be some "standart" way in LXDE? I was searchng but yesterday lxde.org was not available.

Comment: A while back thunar was the default file manager for lubuntu.  However I cant find any info on how the devs did the switch.  I'll keep looking and post back if I find anything.

Comment: Which packages do I need to download in order to use option 2?

Comment: @arno - apart from thunar - you need xfdesktop4 as per the instructions.

Comment: @fossfreedom, re. _edit the file /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart_, it looks that file isn't there in 13.10. There's now a folder called `autostart`.

Answer (score 0):

For how to change and restore Default File Manager, check the link:

[Ubuntu official documentation for Deafult File Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)