# Why is pcmanfm is still running after following the LXDE/XFCE Hybrid instructions?

Tags: lubuntu

OS: Lubuntu 13.04

I'm trying to replace `PCManFM` with `Thunar` and `xfdesktop`. For this, I followed the procedure described in the section titled "LXDE/XFCE Hybrid" [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/73101/25656).

However, after a reboot, the desktop is still controlled by `PCManFM` and when I run `ps -ef` I see this (in part):

```
UID     PID   PPID   C STIME TTY   TIME     CMD
vasa1   1624  1540   0 18:18   ?   00:00:00 pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu
vasa1   1642     1   0 18:18   ?   00:00:00 xfdesktop
```

If I kill the process, `xfdesktop` immediately takes over.

So why is `pcmanfm` still running? Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/73101/25656):

> Stop pcmanfm desktop being run on login: edit the file
>   `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` and change the line `@pcmanfm
>   --desktop --profile lubuntu` to `!@pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu`

no longer effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56439/15760), it is necessary to comment out or delete the same line, `@pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu`, from `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`. After doing this, no pcmanfm process runs and the xfdesktop is in charge.