# PCmanFM - can't interact between 2 windows.

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, thunar, pcmanfm

I have one PCmanFM on the left and one on the right. I can't drag files from the window on the left to the right one. This works in nautilus, and thunar just like I expect it to work. The weird thing is this problem only occurs when both PCmanFm windows are in *detailed list view*. Is this a bug?

In nautilus it works fine if both are in list view. 
[image]

In PCmanFM it does not.

[image]

Comment: Search the internet for "pcmanfm drag-and-drop". This is probably related to a bug in PCManFM though you should always mention the version number of the application..

Comment: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-May/004138.html ; https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32369 ; https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcmanfm/+bug/1179167

Comment: I'd suggest closing this question as relating to a "bug".

Comment: does this mean that if I want to have drag and drop I have to use another file manager. this bug seems to have been present since 2011

Comment: I using option 2 [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73017/thunar-as-default-file-manager-in-lubuntu-11-10-how) for some months now :D

Comment: thanks but I will find something else instead.