# Ubuntu 12.04 connects to some wireless networks but not others

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, lenovo, connection

I installed 12.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad with a broadcom driver. It connects to some wifi networks with no problems. Although some others it keeps trying to configure and then disconnects and tries again.

I am pretty unfamiliar with terminal commands, but I have already tried things suggested in other threads that are like mine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you: [My Lenovo Ideapad u165 wireless doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43529/my-lenovo-ideapad-u165-wireless-doesnt-work)

Some other solution that I found on the web was to connect to your wireless network by typing its name directly, not waiting for the Ubuntu to find it. This solution worked on others operating systems too.

*Source:* http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-S-series-Netbooks/can-t-connect-to-wireless-router/m-p/195364/highlight/true#M6930